# Identify short story where two humans  to save the species follow directions from a computer to procreate

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story. There are my recollections:

- humans are dying too young to reproduce, or learn how to fix things,
- and the computers are not working correctly.

One scene involved two kids trying to follow directions from a computer as to how to procreate to try to save the species.

Comment: I've found the link but can't include it in an answer because scifi.SE filters redtube URLs.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201897/robotic-spaceships-have-a-human-prisoner-to-maintain-them (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 12):

I recognized that one! I read alot of sci-fi when I was younger and had to go through the list of the authors I read, but I found it.

It was a short story by [Harlan Ellison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harlan_Ellison) called [“The Human Operators”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52481). It was made into an [episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Human_Operators) on the TV show *The Outer Limits*.

You can read some reviews of the short story and Ellison's audiobook reading online, e.g. [1](http://www.davecreek.net/blog/?p=122) [2](http://www.islets.net/audio/operators.html).

Comment: Now that you mention that, some aspects of OP recollections are rather Ellison-esque..