# Movie with a one-person crew spaceship. Onboard computer would punish them with shocks for disobedience

Tags: story-identification

Whice sci-fi space movie has a one-person crew? They would be punished for disobedience (by the computer) with electric shocks?

Comment: This question is very terse and would be dramatically improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Denise.  Valorum is correct that the description is pretty brief.  However, based on what you have listed I have taken a stab at an answer below. If this is not the right answer, if you could add any additional information that you remember that could help in identify what you are seeking.  Hope that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: If it IS Human Operators then this is a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201897/robotic-spaceships-have-a-human-prisoner-to-maintain-them Who's description is a little better and may help you confirm if its the same.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like it could be the Outer Limits Season 5 episode [Human Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series)_episodes#Season_5_(1999)).

It is a one hour episode, not a a movie.  But, parts that match include:

*"Humanity constructs advanced military spacecraft, but the ships learn to think for themselves. They kill their crews by disengaging the life support systems. However, they kept a small number of humans alive for repairs they cannot do themselves."*

And

*"...he finds himself angering the ship on numerous occasions. At one point, they are both "racked"; they are subjected to electric shocks."*

Comment: The episode is based on a short story by Harlan Ellison and A. E. Van Vogt.  It's on the Daily Motion website, but I'm not linking as I'm not sure if that site is legit.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt Dailymotion is a video-sharing platform like YouTube, so no, it's probably not legit. Having said that, I do often see people linking to YouTube videos in answers...